# HTML mail received in gmail, outlook are rendered in strike through <s> tag

Tags: html-email, sendgrid, strikethrough

When I am sending an HTML mail through clients like SendGrid, the receiver email id is getting some text in strike through format. Upon inspection, the HTML content is correct while sending but while rendering, outlook/gmail is adding an additional '<s>' tag randomly which causes the strike through text to appear. Has anyone ever faced this issue and if so, what is the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possibly a parsing error to do with your code. Are you able to give us your HTML code you are trying to send?